Text encoding used in filenames of non-text files
Background
We have a system created for a client that uses a Logic App to process some files and pass them to an API which stores the files in blob storage and the file metadata in a database.
When passing files to the API directly, the filename is stored in the database and subsequent requests for the file return the filename exactly as it was uploaded. This includes characters with diacritics etc.
Issue
When using the Logic App, I can see in the run details of each step that the filename is as it was uploaded and it seems this is what is passed to the API.
However, requesting that info from the API shows these extended characters as a question mark ?.
We had similar issues with clients uploading text files that were not encoded with UTF-8, but we pointed this out and it was resolved.
However, we've come across a similar problem with PDFs with extended characters in the filename.
Now, as PDFs are not text files, they don't use text encoding - but what about the filename itself?
Is there any way to determine the encoding used for a filename?
Is it dependent on the filesystem that created the file?
I've done a bunch of digging online and can't find anything specific to filename text encodings. And the client is grumbling about their filenames with missing umlauted letters.
Update
Logic App showing the steps to set various bits of info (filename, category etc), then a step to get the blob content, then an HTTP step to send it to the API:

(NB: 'quote' is simply double quotes. We were having issues getting this working until someone pointed out this handy trick.)
If we run it and look at the logs, we see:

And in the DB at the other end, once processed by the API:

The second row from the DB in this screenshot is uploading the same file directly to the API via Postman. The filename is different because it's prefixed with other info that the Logic App extracts and passes as other values.
That is irrelevant though - what is clear is that if the Logic App grabs the file from Blob Storage, when it calls the API, any characters with diacritics in the title end up as ? in the DB whereas if uploaded to the API directly diacritics are retained in the DB.

The file name is basically always entirely unrelated to the file content. So the "encoding of a PDF file name" has the same problems (and solutions) as the "encoding of a text file name". Some file- and/or operating-systems define the encoding of there file names others (especially unix-likes) tend to treat them as "byte strings with some restrictions" and make it the app developers problem.

Yup, that's why I used a PDF file as an example - to highlight that it's nothing to do with the files encoding.
So it's essentially the same problem as receiving a text file without knowing the encoding - it might look ok or you might need to try a few encodings and see what looks best, as there's no guaranteed way to determine the encoding when receiving a file. Yay.

There is no web encoding involved in this process though. It's an Azure Logic App, pulling a file from Azure Blob Storage and passing it to an API. In the Logic App logs, the filename looks fine (has characters with diacritics). However, when it gets to the API any characters with diacritics are replaced with question marks. Nothing is being passed in a URL.

It would be easier to answer your question if you provided an example showing the Logic App actions and filenames which you are having issues with.

@10p I've updated the question with images. The file currently causing issues contains an umlaut in the filename and is created in Germany. As our client is international, we suspect this might happen frequently in the future, especially with files generated in other markets/countries.

@Jag I don't think  HTTP headers are designed to use Unicode characters... They might need to be transformed to something like %C3%9C%C3%BC in the HTTP headers. Not a Logic App issue per se.

Yeah, it's a pain to check.
It seems to work fine in Postman (sending data as multipart/form-data) but the same file calling the same API endpoint results in different data in the DB.
If we assume that Postman is doing it "right" then we must assume that the Logic App is doing it "wrong". Of course, Postman could be doing some additional magic we're not aware of...

And someone closed it for being "off topic" or not being a programming or programmer tool question.
Yet, it automagically picked up the tags and considers it part of the Microsoft Azure Collective...
If this is part of the MS Azure Collective but not a relevant question for this site, why is the MS Azure Collective on this site?!?
Please don't go the way of Experts Exchange SO :)
